# Reverse a pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i have a simple pointer to an array and i want to reverse that array, this is the code that i wrote:

```
void str_reverse(char *s) {
    int l, r;
    l = 0;
    r = str_len(s) - 1;
    char temp;
    printf("length %i ", r);
    while (l <= r) {
        temp = *(s + l);
        printf("\n%c [%i] | %c [%i]\n", temp, l, *(s + r), r);

        *(s + l) = *(s + r);
        *(s + r) = temp;
        r--;
        l++;
    }
}
```

As you can see i use this fuction:

```
int str_len(char *p) {
    int l = 0;
    while (*(p + l) != '\0') {
//        printf("%c %i", *(p + l),l);
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}
```

I order to get the length of my array, this is my little main

```
int main() {
    char *s = "Hallo world!";

    str_reverse(s);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
length 10 
H [0] | d [10]
Bus error: 10
```

Now i tried to only print the values, so in the while loop of str_reverse i commented this two lines:

```
*(s + l) = *(s + r);
*(s + r) = temp;
```

And this is the output:

```
H [0] | ! [11]

a [1] | d [10]

l [2] | l [9]

l [3] | r [8]

o [4] | o [7]

  [5] | w [6]
```

That is good! But how can i store them? Thank you in advance

Comment: This happens when you call Pointer =>> Array. A Pointer is not an Array and an Array is not a Pointer.

Comment: A pointer points to "something", but an Array don't. Inside the Array "something". Will be copied. That's all...so if you want to copy "something" inside a Pointer, then you need to dinamicaly allocate some memory an use that pointer to point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `main`, `s` points to a string literal.  These literals are typically stored in read only memory, so they can't be modified.

Change `s` to an *array* initialized with a string literal and it will work.

```
char s[] = "Hallo world!";
```

Using dynamically allocated memory will also work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

...

char *s = strdup("Hallo world!");
str_reverse(s);
free(s);
```

Comment: @Francesco You can do it with a pointer, but it can't point to read only memory like `char *s = "Hallo world!";`.  It's fine if it points to an array or to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Francesco And what are those warnings?

Comment: string.c:56:15: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'strdup' with type 'char *(const char *)'
    char *s = strdup("Hallo world!");
              ^
string.c:56:15: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strdup'
string.c:87:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    free(s);
    ^
2 warnings generated.

Comment: @Francesco Then you need to include `string.h` and `stdlib.h`.  See my edit.

Comment: Strdup is not a C standard library.